# How to ignore wrong cin input in C++?

Tags: c++, cin

This is code for a 4x4 tic-tac-toe game. I am new to programming. I don't know how to ignore wrong input from the user. I tried searching Google, I found `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore()`. They did work a little bit, but not fully working. For example, if the user enters `11111111 4 o` as input, the program exits instead of ignoring this. How to ignore this input?

And what are `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore()` doing?

```cpp
char game[4][4]; 
int r, c;
char ans;
cin >> r >> c >> ans;
--r, --c;
if (!check_ok(r, c, ans)){
    cout << "try again: select available ones only!!!\n";
    --count;//count checks for 16 turns through while loop

}else{
    game[r][c] = ans;
    ++count1;
}
```

```cpp
bool Game::check_ok(int a, int b, char an) {
    if (game[a][b] == ' ' && a < 4 && b < 4  && ((count1 % 2 == 0 && an == 'x') || (count1 % 2 != 0 && an == 'o'))){
        game[a][b] = an;
        return true;
    }
    else{
       cin.clear();
       cin.ignore();
       return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. User input is hard.

Interactive user input is line based.
User inputs some values and then hits return. This flushes the stream and unblocks the readers to get the value from the stream. So you should design your input code to be line based.

The first question seems to be is all the input on one line or do they input the values with a return between each? You can determine this with some outut to the user then follow the rules defined by your instructions.

So lets do a line based input example:

```
do {
    // Your instructions can be better.
    std::cout << "Input: Row Col Answer <enter>\n";

    // Read the user input. 1 Line of text.
    std::string  line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    // convert user input into a seprate stream
    // See if we can correctly parse it.
    std::stringstream linestream(std::move(line));

    // Notice we check if the read worked.
    // and that the check_ok() returns true.
    // No point in call check_ok() if the read failed.
    if (linestream >> r >> c >> ans && check_ok(r, c, ans)) {
        break;
    }
    std::cout << "Invalid Input. Please try again\n";
}
while(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

i think instead of ignoring the wrong input you should limit the users input into the ideal inputs only. maybe an if statement could help

```
if(input != ideal_input)
{
    cout>>"invalid input";
}
else
{
    //progress in the game
}
```